# Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: class WordViewModel has no zero argument constructor

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-viewmodel

Cannot instantiate WordViewModel
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.example.roomwordsample.WordViewModel has no zero argument constructor

I am trying to display room data with recycler view but I cannot instantiate class via ViewModelProvider get method

WordViewModel.kt

```
package com.example.roomwordsample

import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class WordViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val repository: WordRepository
    // Using LiveData and caching what getAlphabetizedWords returns has several benefits:
    // - We can put an observer on the data (instead of polling for changes) and only update the
    //   the UI when the data actually changes.
    // - Repository is completely separated from the UI through the ViewModel.
    val allWords: LiveData<List<Word>>


    init {
        val wordsDao = WordRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).wordDao()
        repository = WordRepository(wordsDao)
        allWords = repository.allWords
    }

    /**
     * Launching a new coroutine to insert the data in a non-blocking way
     */
    fun insert(word: Word) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.insert(word)
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.roomwordsample

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val newWordActivityRequestCode = 1
    private lateinit var wordViewModel: WordViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerview)
        val adapter = WordListAdapter(this)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        wordViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(WordViewModel::class.java)
        wordViewModel.allWords.observe(this, Observer { words ->
            // Update the cached copy of the words in the adapter.
            words?.let { adapter.setWords(it) }
        })

        val fab = findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fab)
        fab.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, NewWordActivity::class.java)
            startActivityForResult(intent, newWordActivityRequestCode)
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == newWordActivityRequestCode && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            data?.getStringExtra(NewWordActivity.EXTRA_REPLY)?.let {
                val word = Word(it)
                wordViewModel.insert(word)
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext,
                R.string.empty_not_saved,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by

```
wordViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(WordViewModel::class.java)
```

changing the above code with this:

```
wordViewModel = ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(application).create(WordViewModel::class.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add view model factory to your view model class.

```
package com.example.roomwordsample

import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class WordViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val repository: WordRepository
    // Using LiveData and caching what getAlphabetizedWords returns has several benefits:
    // - We can put an observer on the data (instead of polling for changes) and only update the
    //   the UI when the data actually changes.
    // - Repository is completely separated from the UI through the ViewModel.
    val allWords: LiveData<List<Word>>


    init {
        val wordsDao = WordRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).wordDao()
        repository = WordRepository(wordsDao)
        allWords = repository.allWords
    }

    /**
     * Launching a new coroutine to insert the data in a non-blocking way
     */
    fun insert(word: Word) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.insert(word)
    }

class Factory(
        private val app: Application
    ) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(WordViewModel::class.java)) {
                return WordViewModel(app) as T
            }
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your MainActivity intialize your view model like this:

```
package com.example.roomwordsample

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val newWordActivityRequestCode = 1
    private val wordViewModel by viewModels<WordViewModel> {
        WordViewModel.Factory(application)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerview)
        val adapter = WordListAdapter(this)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        //wordViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(WordViewModel::class.java)
        wordViewModel.allWords.observe(this, Observer { words ->
            // Update the cached copy of the words in the adapter.
            words?.let { adapter.setWords(it) }
        })

        val fab = findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fab)
        fab.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, NewWordActivity::class.java)
            startActivityForResult(intent, newWordActivityRequestCode)
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == newWordActivityRequestCode && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            data?.getStringExtra(NewWordActivity.EXTRA_REPLY)?.let {
                val word = Word(it)
                wordViewModel.insert(word)
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext,
                R.string.empty_not_saved,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }


}
```